# Does the Stable Matching Algorithm always return a stable matching?

Tags: algorithms

I am currently reading some online notes on this problem and one source says that in order to find a stable matching we could brute force the problem and test every perfect matching. However, I thought that the algorithm always returns a stable matching at completion? If so, why would you need to brute force it?